# why xaxis and yaxis ticks don't appear on axes in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm using d3 v5 to create a data visualization of a three column CSV file. The code I've written for the axes draws the axes, but the ticks don't appear. When I directly input integers into domain, the ticks appear, but apparently the domain doesn't get the max value from my data. I need help with this, please.

```
var dataset = [];

var w = 1000;
var h = 600;
var padding = 30;


d3.csv("nobel-prize.csv", d3.autoType(), function(d) {
    return {
        Year: +d.Year,
        Women: +d.Women,
        Men: +d.Men
    };

}).then(function(data) {

    dataset = data;

    console.log(data);


});

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
               .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, d => d.Year)])
               .range([padding, w - padding * 2])
               .nice();


var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
               .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, d => d.Men)])
               .range([h - padding, padding])
               .nice();


var xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
              .scale(xScale)

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
              .scale(yScale)


var svg = d3.select("svg")

            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

            svg.append("g")
            .call(xAxis)
            .attr("class", "axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (h - padding) + ")")


         svg.append("g")
            .call(yAxis)
            .attr("class", "axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ", 0)")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the code located after the `.then` function is running before the CSV data is retrieved, hence when `dataset` is an empty array.

The code defining axes and drawing the chart should be moved accordingly, inside the `.then` function.

```
.then(function(data) {

    dataset = data;

    console.log(data);

   // here

});
```

Other remark: the x scale is currently defined to show all years between 0 and the max of the dataset:

```
.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, d => d.Year)])
```

Assuming the chart will display Nobel prize winners,you probably want the chart to start in 1901 (or use the `min` value found in the dataset).